# Append as a paragraph with number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I append this as a paragraph with a auto number per line. The below example is in listview. See the link .Its working.

[**Working Demo but in listview**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Z7uxZ/)

My Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" id="custom-listview">

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Js codes

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
var split = 'Cook pasta according to directions, chill in ice water, drain.¶Blanch broccoli in boiling water, chill in ice water, drain.¶Use ½ soy sauce to season the chicken, heat oil in no stick pan, brown chicken, and reduce heat and finish cooking.¶Don"t overcook! Slice chicken into 1" strips, turn and cut into ¼" pieces, place into bowl with other ingredients except dressing and soy sauce.¶Mix remainder of soy sauce into dressing and pour over pasta, chicken, and vegetables.¶Toss gently and serve immediately.¶You might like to leave the pasta, chicken, broccoli un-chilled and serve it semi-warm';

var lines = split.split('¶');
$.each(lines, function(key, line) {
    $('#custom-listview').append('<li><a href="#">' + line + '</a></li>');
});
$('#custom-listview').listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7uxZ/1/ - `key` is actually an `index` in your example.

Comment: how can I start in 1 ?

Comment: `(key+1)` - just add 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a variable and increase it for each item you append.

```
var number = 1;
$.each(lines, function(key, line) {
    $('#custom-listview').append('<li><a href="#">' + number + '. ' + line + '</a></li>');
    number++;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7uxZ/2/